# initialization of multiarray raised unreported exception python

Tags: python, numpy

I am a new programmer who is picking up python. I recently am trying to learn about importing csv files using numpy. 
Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.loadtxt("abcd.py", delimiter = True, unpack = True)
print(x)
```

The idle returns me with:

```
>> True
>> Traceback (most recent call last):
>>  File "C:/Python34/Scripts/a.py", line 1, in <module>
    import numpy as np

>>  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 180, in <module>
    from . import add_newdocs

>>  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\numpy\add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc

>>  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .type_check import *

>>  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\type_check.py", line 11, in <module>
    import numpy.core.numeric as _nx

>>  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from . import multiarray

>> SystemError: initialization of multiarray raised unreported exception
```

Why do I get the this system error and how can I remedy it?

Answer (score 4):

I have experienced this problem too. This is cuased by a file named "datetime.py" in the same folder (exactly the same problem confronted by [Bruce](https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/forum/#!topic/anaconda/VqRUdoA-LnA)). Actually "datetime" is an existing python module. However, I do not know why running my own script, *e.g.* `plot.py` will invoke my `datetime.py` file (I have seen the output produced by my `datetime.py`, and there will be an auto-generated `datetime.cpython-36.pyc` in the `__pycache__` folder).

Although I am not clear about how the error is triggered, after I rename my `datetime.py` file to other names, I can run the `plot.py` immediately. Therefore, I suggest you check if there are some files whose name collides with the system modules. (P.S. I use the Visual Studio Code to run python.)

Comment: Newer versions of NumPy display the correct exception: `AttributeError: module 'datetime' has no attribute 'datetime_CAPI'`. The reason your file causes this error  is explained at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38540144.

Answer (score 3):

As there is an error at the import line, your installation of numpy is broken in some way. My guess is that you have installed numpy for python2 but are using python3. You should remove numpy and attempt a complete re-install, taking care to pick the correct version.

There are a few oddities in the code:
You are apparently reading a python file, `abcd.py`, not a csv file. Typically you want to have your data in a csv file.

The delimiter is a string, not a boolean, typically `delimiter=","` ([Documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html))

```
import numpy as np
x = np.loadtxt("abcd.csv", delimiter = ",", unpack = True)
```